# How to filter out the records with the latest date?

Tags: wordpress

I have a table with id, task_id, created_taskaction (= rec.cr.date).

I would like to get the latest record for e.g. task_id 0001.

In the wordpress framework I tried this:

```
> $last_task_action2=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->task_actions
> NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT id_task, MAX(created_taskaction) AS datetime
> FROM $wpdb->task_actions GROUP BY id_task) mostrecent ON
> $wpdb->task_actions.id_task = $wpdb->mostrecent.id_task  AND
> $wpdb->task_actions.datetime = $wpdb->mostrecent.datetime");
```

But it doesn't work. I tried copying from this thread, but it's still confusing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Even these two don't show ANY data...

```
$last_task_actiond = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MAX (created_taskaction) AS 'Max' FROM $wpdb->task_actions");
echo $last_task_actiond;
```

and

```
$last_task_actiond = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MAX (created_taskaction) AS 'Max' FROM wp_task_actions");
echo $last_task_actiond;
```

Nothing shows up...

Comment: What database is this?  MYSQL?

Comment: It's a MYSQL DB I'm using with PHP MyAdmin. But I often use the wordpress language with SQL coding. Also the dhtmlx framework with their Php connector and mysql syncing.

Comment: Do you want the latest row for a specific `task_id` or for each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

It worked I found 2 bugs:

Line 5:

> $wpdb->task_actions.datetime = $wpdb->mostrecent.datetime");
>   Had to be: `task_actions.created_taskaction` instead of `task_actions.datetime`

Also the `$wpdb->` sometimes doesn't work properly, so I changed all of them with `wp_`